# com.google.android.gms.ads, code: 3, message: Received error HTTP response code: 403

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, ads

I had published my app on Google Play Store, initially ads came for 2-3 days but after that ads stopped coming. I searched then came to know that there is issue of app-ads.txt file, I fixed it, still ads did not come, I generated new ads unit ID, still I am getting this error

domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, code: 3, message: Received error HTTP response code: 403

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Make sure that your app is approved on AdMob, doesn't have any policy violations, etc & you have completed all the steps on the dashboard like pin/address verification, adding payment info, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Received error HTTP response code: 403" means that the Google Ads service is refusing to authorize your request. This can happen for a number of reasons, including:

**1. You are not logged in to your Google account.**

**2. You do not have permission to access the requested resource.**

**3. The Google Ads service is experiencing technical difficulties.**

To resolve this issue, try the following:

1. **Make sure that you are logged in to your Google account.**
2. **Check your permissions to make sure that you have access to the
   requested resource.**

Comment: That's a pretty good answer, do you have a source for it?

Comment: I have check above mentioned instructions, all is fine but ads are not showing in my app.

Comment: can you please provide a code to check what's the issue actually?